# Calculation on keypress event (or number only in keyup event)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to calculate a discount and allowing numbers only in the discount field. When I use the keyup event, the calculation is right but I still can type any characters, if I use the keypress event, the restriction on characters works but the calculation does not work anymore (the first input is not recorded).

Here is a codepen of my code : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/jEzBGy?editors=101

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $discount = $('#discount'),
        $price = $('#price'),
        $newPrice = $('#new-price');


    $discount.on('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)){
            return false;
        }
    $newPrice.val(
        Math.round(
            ($price.val() - (($discount.val() / 100) * $price.val()))* 100) / 100
        );
    });
});
```

I used an answer from stackoverflow to check the numbers.

Thanks by advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine both `keypress` and `keyup` events to achieve this. Use `keypress` to prevent unwanted characters, and `keyup` for the actual calculation.

You'll also have to use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` to make sure `keyup` won't proceed with the calculation even when an invalid character entered:

```
$discount.on('keypress', function(e)
{
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }
}
.on('keyup change', function(e)
{
    $newPrice.val(Math.round(($price.val() - (this.value / 100) * $price.val()))* 100) / 100);
});
```

I took the liberty to hook for a `change` event as well, so the total will get updated when you delete characters (using <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> key) as well.

See updated [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwRpXZ)

Answer (score 2):

Use both `keyup keypress` like this.

```
$discount.on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        }
```

But i guess in your code you are also disabling `delete, left, right, backspace` which a user won't like i guess.

Here is a function which is more user friendly and allows `number, left, right, backspace, delete`.

```
function validateQty(event) {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46
 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) {
    return true;
}
else if ( key < 48 || key > 57 ) {
    return false;
}
else return true;
};
```

And to use it, do,

```
$discount.on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return validateQty(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that works great!

Html code :

```
Qty:<input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value='' /> <br/>
Price:<input type='text' name='price' id='price' /> <br/>
Total:<input type='text' name='total' id='total' /> <br/>
```

And script :

```
$('#qty, #price').on('input', function () {
    var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val());
    var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
    $('#total').val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));
});
```

Test here : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/egzontina/zqqtepu8/1/)